# Dictionary: assign name of list to dictionary if string in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, assign

**Set up**

I have the following list of lists of groups,

```
lofl=[A,B,...,N]
```

where each group contains subgroups,

```
A=['A1','A2','A3',...,An]
B=['B1','B2','B3',...,Bn]
# ⋮           ⋮
N=['N1','N2','N3',...,Nn]
```

Finally, I have a dictionary `data`.

---

**Intention**

I want to check if e.g. the subgroup `An` is in `lofl`, and if so, I want to assign its string name `'A'` to `data['group']` and assign `An` to `data['subgroup']`.

*Note*: in my actual data set, `A,B,...,N` and `An,Bn,...,Nn` are all names without numbers.

---

**Current code**

```
if x in lofl:
   if x in A:
      data['group']='A'
      data['subgroup']=x
   elif x in B:
      data['group']='B'
      data['subgroup']=x
   #     ⋮
   elif x in N:
      data['group']='N'
      data['subgroup']=x
   else:
      data['group']='unknown'
      data['subgroup']=x
```

---

**Problem**

The code is a bit long. Moreover, I want to reuse the code on different datasets, for which the group names differ. I'd like to avoid to have to replace the names in the code for each dataset. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the long list of names, each referencing a list? Move those into a dictionary, so you can just use a loop over the key-value pairs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How would I do that loop over key-value pairs? I'm new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid long lists of variable names that all point to the same kind of data. Use a dictionary instead:

```
subgroups = {
    'A': ['A1','A2','A3',...,An]
    'B': ['B1','B2','B3',...,Bn],
    # ⋮           ⋮
    'N': ['N1','N2','N3',...,Nn],
}
```

Now you can replace your separate `if..elif..else` tree with a loop:

```
if x in lofl:
    data['subgroup'] = x
    for name, subgroup in subgroups.items():
        if x in subgroup:
            data['group'] = name
            break
    else:
        data['group'] = 'unknown'
```

You may want to consider creating indices; looping over all those lists and testing each one is *expensive* (each `in` test must loop through the full list for instance). Consider using sets instead of lists (testing for set membership takes O(1) constant time rather than O(N) linear time) and/or an index (like a dictionary mapping values in the `subgroups` lists to the key they belong to, so all you have to do is use `index.get(x, 'unknown')` rather than a loop).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll switch to dictionaries and try this out! I call them lists but I should've called them sets. All the groups and subgroups are unique.

Comment: The code doesn't work. That is, it assigns `'unknown'` to all `data['group']`. I've changed the code a bit: now it does not assign `'unknown'` anymore. However, instead of assigning e.g. the correct `subgroup` name `A`, it assigns `A1,A2,...An` to `data['group']`. I think I need to change the line 'data['group'] = subgroup' to something like 'data['group'] = subgroup.name()'. Do you know the command to do this? I've been searching for 30 min now.

Comment: @LucSpan: this is why I asked you (on the question) if you were assigning the group name. Your code suggested you were assigning the whole list. Please do respond to such comments and update your question to correct the error.

Comment: My bad, I only saw your answer. I thought it was clear in the question, I'll update.

Comment: @LucSpan: I updated it just now, as well as my answer. The names are the keys in the dictionary. I can't assess why the `x in subgroup` test fails for you as you didn't share a sample input with expected output; the loop otherwise accurately reflects your sample decision tree.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks a lot, and my apologies for the inconvenience.